# OPENGL Rendering different textures & performance

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am developing a game using the LWJGL library. I have got few different textures to render. I am using the textures as sprite sheets and i need to render some object at a time, for an example in the order of:  player -> blocks -> npc -> mobs.

I've tried the following:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.id);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
{
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, 100);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex2f(100, 100);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2f(100, 0);
}
glEnd();
```

But what if i want to use only single `glBegin()` to render, I have discovered that there are only few methods you can use inside `glBegin()` and `glBindTexture()` is not in there.

So my question is actually if theres a way to change textures inside the `glBegin()`, and if not is it good for performance to use more than one `glBegin()` and `glEnd()` loops?

Comment: If your texture is a spritesheet, then why do you have to change texture?

Comment: Cause each sprite sheet takes another type of object. (ex: player, monsters, blocks, and more..)

Comment: glBegin(GL_QUADS); will hurt your performance... switch to modern opengl (3.+). You could use texture atlases to minimize number of texture changes. How many texture do you have? 2...3... or every quad has a different texture?

Comment: To back up fen, I'd like to add that for a reasonably complex game it's not a matter of 60fps vs 30 fps but more in the magnitude of 60fps vs 3 fps. The difference between a game and a powerpoint. Not that what you are doing now is bad (its great for learning), it's just not the way you want to do it in the end. Search for VBO's VAO's and texturearrays/atlasses if you are up for the challenge.